# Executing spring web client causing DeferringLoadBalancerExchangeFilterFunction non qualifying bean exception

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-feign

I have created spring boot project with Spring WebFlux. Idea is to learn the Spring WebClient and related stuff. On start of application, I am getting below error

```
Error creating bean with name 'loadBalancerWebClientBuilderBeanPostProcessor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/client/loadbalancer/reactive/LoadBalancerBeanPostProcessorAutoConfiguration.class]: 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'loadBalancerWebClientBuilderBeanPostProcessor' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.reactive.DeferringLoadBalancerExchangeFilterFunction<?>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. 
Dependency annotations: {}
```

I have dependencies like spring-cloud-dependencies/spring-boot-starter*/spring-cloud-context in my maven dependencies. Error just giving information that DeferrringLoadBalancerExchangeFilterFunction is not available, I have tried to inject it using @Bean in my configuration class. But error still persists. Please advice

Posting dependencies in pom.xml

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Hoxton.SR9</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

 <dependencies>

  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-all</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  

    <!-- 3rd Party Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
        <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
        <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-keyvault-secrets-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-context</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!--Dependency for registering your app as a Spring Boot Admin Client-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jolokia</groupId>
        <artifactId>jolokia-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>    

    <!--spring dependencies-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-feign</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-jwt</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <!--swagger dependency-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--3rd party dependencies-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.12</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
        <artifactId>jwks-rsa</artifactId>
        <version>0.14.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.openfeign</groupId>
        <artifactId>feign-gson</artifactId>
        <version>9.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.nimbusds</groupId>
        <artifactId>nimbus-jose-jwt</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Please note that i use feign client as well as web client in my code. Not sure whether that has an impact

Comment: Try adding `spring-cloud-starter-loadbalancer` to your pom. If that does not help, please post your entire pom.

Comment: @OlgaMaciaszek - I have tried that but still same exception. This is happening only when i have webflex and fiegn client combination i think

Comment: That is not a full pom.

Comment: Please remove explicitly added spring cloud feign version and use the dependency that comes with the bom (`spring-cloud-starter-openfeign`) - let me know if that helps.  If not, please paste your entire pom file.

Comment: @OlgaMaciaszek Thanks this helps. I removed openfeign starter and it is working.

Answer (score 2):

Adding dependency to `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-loadbalancer` helped in my case, as adviced by @OlgaMaciaszek

Comment: for versions spring 2.6.6, cloud 2021.0.1 and i use webflux as well, this was the only solution that helped!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I faced the problem with similar root cause.
To use Spring Cloud with Spring Boot you have to respect [versions compatibility](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud#adding-spring-cloud-to-an-existing-spring-boot-application).
I had a project based on Spring Boot (2.3.12.RELEASE) and Spring Cloud (Hoxton.SR11) which is fine.
But I also tried to use the latest version of `com.playtika.reactivefeign:feign-reactive:3.0.3` which actually relies on Spring Cloud (2020.0.x)

As a result I've faced the same error

```
Error creating bean with name 'loadBalancerWebClientBuilderBeanPostProcessor'`
```

In my case I've downgraded reactivefeign version to 2.0.31

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved this by removing unnecessary dependency which was causing issues for this issue  that is :
'org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.reactive.DeferringLoadBalancerExchangeFilterFunction' that could not be found.

```
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
```